# Pandas Find Index Value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the index value for "Rental Income" in the dataframe below.  The dataframe is being uploaded from an Excel document and needs to be cleaned.

Is there a way to find the index value for "Rental Income" without given the column name or row name?  The formatting is different in ever Excel file so the column and row names change with each file.  But if I can search the full dataframe at once, I can you the reference as the anchor point.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with `where` then `stack`

```
out = df.where(df.eq('A1')).stack()
idx = out.index.get_level_values(0)
col = out.index.get_level_values(1)
```